# What's the difference between a directory symlink and a file symlink on Windows?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, windows-11

Why does `mklink` have a `/d` flag?

Why aren't all symlinks identical in how they work. Aren't directories just files anyway?

Comment: Windows has a clear distinction between a file and folder, all the way from DOS, but that's besides the point for this question. There are different types of links because they offer different features. A hardlink is placed on such low level that the software layer can't detect them unless they have administrative privileges, but they can only run on the same harddisk. A softlink is like a shortcut, and can link to other devices, such as a network share, but the OS will know, without administrative privileges, that this is a shortcut. And a Junction is basically in between.

Comment: @LPChip why couldn't `mklink folder_link folder_source` just detect that `folder_source` is a folder, and then apply the necessary differences? Why are there any differences in the first place though? What is different between the data of `folder_link` and `file_link`? Why is that necessary?

Comment: That is how the filesystem was originally designed in DOS. An entry is either a file or folder, and cannot be treated indestinctly. On a file level, it is possible for the source or target to be both a file and a folder, so one have to specify what you want.

Comment: @LPChip are symlinks also "entries", so they also have to be specified as either files or folders?

Comment: @LPChip how can something be a file _and_ a folder at the same time?

Comment: A filename without an extension can have the exact same name as a folder. In that case, you will have a file and a folder with the same name, and most cmd tools will not be able to deal with it unless the tool is only designed for a folder or file, or it has a parameter switch to specify what you have. This is also why xcopy will ask you if your target is supposed to be a file or folder in some extremely unique cases.

Comment: @LPChip: [citation needed] for that one. Which filesystem works this way?

Comment: You're asking about a system which requires `cd /d` in 2023 and that's way more annoying for daily work. This can't be accurately answered, only a generic "Microsoft likes to stick to outdated historical solutions" can be given.

Comment: @user1686 i assumed all windows filesystems would do, but just tested and NTFS does not allow this. I know FAT16 had this, and I assume FAT32 may also have this, but I have no way to test it right now.

Comment: I can kind of imagine FAT allowing that "by accident" (deliberately inserting a duplicate into the linear list of names, the OS searching for "name matches AND 'directory' attribute set" and skipping over the non-'directory' entry), but most newer filesystems keep directory listings in structures like btrees that don't really have the ability to have duplicate entries at all... You *can* get a similar effect by creating entries that only differ only in case, though (e.g. 'Foo' and 'foo') and won't be able to access them on a case-insensitive OS, but that is not "exact same name".